# How to test existence of an specific redux form with Jest and Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, redux-form, enzyme

I'm using Jest and Enzyme to write unit tests. At one of my React components I render two distinct redux forms.
A simplified version of it would be like:

```
// my_app.js

import React from 'react'
import MyForm from './my_form'
import MyOtherForm from './my_other_form'
class MyApp extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyForm />
        <MyOtherForm />
      </div>
    )
  }
}


// my_form.js

let MyForm = () => <form className='my-form' />
MyForm = reduxForm({ form: 'myForm' })(MyForm)
export default connect(state => state)(MyForm)


// my_other_form.js

let MyOtherForm = () => <form className='my-other-form' />
MyOtherForm = reduxForm({ form: 'myOtherForm' })(MyOtherForm)
export default connect(state => state)(MyOtherForm)
```

Write a simple test just to console log a shallow rendering would look like:

```
// test.js

import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import MyApp from './my_app'
describe('<MyApp />'), () => {
  let wrapper = shallow(<MyApp />)
  it('should test something', () => {

    console(wrapper.debug())

  })
}
```

Would log something like:

```
<div>
  <Connect(ReduxForm) />
  <Connect(ReduxForm) />
</div>
```

How can I assert that both MyForm and MyOtherForm were rendered correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use provider.
I use 'mount' instead of 'shallow' when using Provider. 
Here is an example.

```html
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';

import LoginForm from '../LoginForm';

const mockStore = configureMockStore();
const dispatch = jest.fn();
const handleSubmit = jest.fn();
const onSubmit = jest.fn();
let store;
const initProps = {
  onSubmit,
};

describe('LoginForm', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    store = mockStore({
      handleSubmit,
      dispatch,
    });
    dispatch.mockClear();
  });
  
  it('renders without exploding', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <LoginForm {...initProps} />
      </Provider>,
    );

    expect(wrapper).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(wrapper.find('button').prop('disabled')).toBe(true);
  });
 });
```

Otherwise, you can wrap your form simply.

```html
// LoginForm.jsx
const LoginForm = (props) => (
  <form>
    ...
  </form>
);

// LoginFormWrapper.jsx
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'loginForm',
})(LoginForm);

// index.js
export { default } from './LoginFormWrapper';


//test.spec.js
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';

describe('LoginForm', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<LoginForm />);
  expect(wrapper).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the point. The point is having two distinct forms in the same component, tell if both have rendered properly. Got it?